# A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

**New in Flutter**

When I run my app on android studio, I got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: defaultConfig contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.
```

I tried to solve the issue
below you can find the **app\build.gardle**, **android/build.gardle**, **gardle-wrapper.properties**
Please help! Thank you in advance!

***The code in app\build.gardle :**

```
// Add the Google services Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    


    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

   

    *buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }*

    buildToolsVersion '33.0.2'

    namespace 'com.android.application'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.5.0')
}
```

***The code for android/build.gardle:**

```
buildscript {
    

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'


    }
}


}
```

***The code for gardle-wrapper.properties :**

```
#Mon May 01 01:28:58 EET 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
```